# Ejabberd : Not able to connect web console

Tags: ubuntu, ejabberd

I have installed ejabber in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

It is an AWS instance.

I have opened ports 5222, 5269, 5280.
Changed the /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml with 
hosts, acl with admin user.

I have changed the domain name of the server in /etc/hosts.

Added a hosted zone in AWS Route 53.

Am able to create user using ejabberdctl.

And able to login as the user in pidgin in my windows laptop.

But only not able connect to the web console.
http://my.example.com:5280/admin returns Empty response.

same empty response with curl too.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ejabberd uses the certificate which can be found in the directories where the ejabberd is installed.

Try using **https** instead of plain **http**.

I tried this and it works.

And ensure that you have entered the user as admin in  ejabberd.yml configuration file.

under Access Control Lists

```
acl:
##
## The 'admin' ACL grants administrative privileges to XMPP accounts.
## You can put here as many accounts as you want.
##
admin:
 user:
   - "user@yourdomain.com"
```